# Hibernate @OneToMany mapping is giving exception,

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Can you help me what is wrong with this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vendor_po")
public class VendorPO {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "vendor_po_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long vendor_po_id;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = false, cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, 
    CascadeType.CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private List<PaymentMethods> payments = new ArrayList<PaymentMethods>();
}
```

I am getting this exception.

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2706' for key 'UK_8490nkhe03w8piq2nitrma5ok'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. If question is not clear please ask for details.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague helped me solve this problem as he was saying that you should use **ManyToMany** mapping for this kind of situation.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "vendorpo_payment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_po_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id"))
    private List<PaymentMethods> payments = new ArrayList<PaymentMethods>();
```